# How to store a big number in a variable

Tags: vb.net

Nothing works, tried ULong, integer, uint64, biginteger, decimal. how to store this number in the variable? Option strict on

error: Overflow

```
Dim Number_N As Integer = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
     Dim Number_N As ULong = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
     Dim Number_N As UInt64 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
    Dim Number_N As BigInteger = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
    Dim Number_N As Decimal = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `BigInteger` but you can't represent a `BigInteger` as a literal as you can with other numeric data types because it's not part of the language. You would have to represent the number in a `String` literal and call `BigInteger.Parse`:

```
Dim Number_N = BigInteger.Parse("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663")
```